# Python docstring parsing(and generally parsing languages in Python)

Tags: python, parsing, docstring

I would like to generate useful documentation for a REST API written in Python.

I imagine it should be something like this:

```
'''
/kittens/
This method creates kittens in the browser

HTTP Params:
    format(default=json): The format in which kittens will be generated.
    count(default=10): The number of kittens to generate.

Returns:
    A list of kittens.
'''
```

My syntax is obviously:

```
program = dict
dict = repeated(name:string | name:dict)
```

I would like to parse this format and get (for example) a Python dict, preferably without using regex.

Is there a parser for such a syntax already available?
If not, then what is the simplest way of defining and parsing DSLs in Python?

Note that I would prefer *not* to use reStructuredText or any format different from what I described.

Comment: Why don't you want to use reStructuredText or any other existing format?

Comment: Because I specifically want to use the format I described. If reStructuredText supports it, I would gladly use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but reStructuredText can be used to capture the information in your example:

```
.. method:: kittens(format="json", count=10)

   Creates kittens in the browser.

   :param format: The format in which kittens will be generated.
   :param count: The number of kittens to generate.
   :return: A list of kittens
```

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) understands this syntax, which is an extension of the basic reST markup defined by [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I noted that I don't want to use. It's a different syntax. And it's most definitely not human readable. I want people to be able to read the docs *without* having to compile it first.

Comment: @x10: Then I think the answer must be: it is very unlikely that there is parser for your particular syntax already available. You have to roll your own (perhaps you can use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply)).

Answer (score 0):

http://sphinx.pocoo.org/

Its a online documentation tool. Its awesome and it will do exactly what you want.